# How can I mathematically read this map $f:A\longrightarrow B$?

Tags: terminology

In Group Theory I found a "$f:A\longrightarrow B$" but I don’t know how to pronounce this term in English. I know there is a mathematical term for ":" and "$\longrightarrow$" in the map "$f:A\longrightarrow B$". Can anyone tell me that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, in a more complete example: $f:A \to B : a \mapsto f(a)$

"The function $f$ maps values from $A$ to values from $B$. Every value $a \in A$ is mapped to $f(a) \in B$."

Comment: No problem: And by the way: The arrow for $f: A \to B$ is written as \to in LaTeX (this gives a shorter arrow with the same length as the arrow of \mapsto)

Answer (score 2):

"$f$ is a function that maps $A$ to $B$" or "$f$ is a function that takes elements of $A$ to elements of $B$", I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "$f$ is a map from $A$ to $B$," or if the word map can be confused with something else, $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$.